# Can functions and function pointers be used in ObjC just as they are in C?

Tags: objective-c, c, function, syntax

I am familiar with C and am now learning Objective-C.

I often use function pointers

```
void (*callback)(int*restrict, char*restrict)
```

Will that be usable in Objective-C? Especially in structs, like so:

```
struct mytype myvar = {
    .first = myCallback;
    .second = myCallback2;
}
```

Also, I wish to have function prototypes like

```
void function(int * restrict a, char * restrict b);
char * function (char * a);
...
```

Are there no problems with using this style?

Comment: Objective-C (for iOS / Xcode) is [backed by clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) and the "C" it supports .. "Clang is designed to support the C family of programming languages, which includes C, Objective-C .. In addition to these base languages and their dialects, Clang supports a broad variety of language extensions .. to be compatible with the GCC, Microsoft, and other popular compilers as well as to improve functionality through Clang-specific features."

Comment: App Store compliance is off-topic here, so I've edited your question to be strictly about the syntax and language capabilities you're interested in. For more info, please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Comment: @Josh : thanks for the links. Will dig into it :) +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.**

You can use any C strategy that you choose in your Objective-C app. You will still have to write some Objective-C in order to start your `UIApplication` (or use a third-party tool to do it for you).

One thing to keep in mind, though, is that `int` will be a different length depending on the machine and you should explicitly choose `int32_t` or `int16_t` or `int8_t` if you really don't want to use the `NSInteger` `typedef` that abstracts this machine difference.

Comment: Absolutely Ian, uint32_t, int32_t and so on are my friends. Nice. No corner case(s) to know of ?

Comment: I haven't found any yet. Let me know if you run into anything strange.

Comment: You can use them even if you only slightly want.  ObjectiveC is a strict superset of C.  So the accepted answer should be an unequivocal YES.  ps BOOL is also fundamentally different from 32-64 bit, because the 32bit BOOL is actually older than C's bool..

Answer (score 4):

Clang (the default compiler used by Xcode) claims C11 support for Objective C (See [Language Compatibility](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#c)).

This means function pointers, restrict, structs, and declarations will all work as you would expect.

One word of advice: don't fight the system; it will create more work for yourself and less reliable software for your users. Programmers should be like water.

> Empty your mind, be formless, shapeless — like water. Now you put water in a cup, it becomes the cup; You put water into a bottle it becomes the bottle; You put it in a teapot it becomes the teapot. Now water can flow or it can crash. Be water, my friend.

— [Bruce Lee](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bruce_Lee)

Comment: Never stop yourself, crush everything you can and be plain evil : the edema which killed him. Two visions. Same goal. But I get your point :)